# Outlook add in development

Tags: outlook

Actually I have developed one custom add in.That add in activates when we click that add in button.But I need to activate that add in when we open the outlook mail without clicking button.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with certain limitations. You would need to implement pinnable task pane, which allow to pin your add-in when moving from message to message. More on the topic: [Implement a pinnable task pane in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane)